# make radgrid column header editable in webforms

Tags: asp.net, telerik

i need to edit my column header of rad grid at run time.
currently the header is not editable not found any events like 'columnheaderclick' in radgrid

So what should i do to enable this feature..

regards,

Sivajith S.

Answer (score 0):

I think the possible way is using `telerik:GridTemplateColumn` .
Here is example ,

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <HeaderTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="yourHeaderTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           ...............       
        </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

You can add any control in `headerTemplate` .
I suggest , you should add a textbox and a button to save your edit . Good Luck :)